# How to backup salesforce data?

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I have to take daily backup of my Salesforce records and store at a particular location .

How can we take daily backup of records from Salesforce and also , store the backup taken at a particular location.

If any possible way ,other than any appexchange app, which can be also be automated, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the data using the data loader which will also helps you to make choice between the objects & fields to be exported. 
Below is workaround:
I)

1. You can schedule from set up -> Data Managment -> Data Export -> Schedule export.
2. Schedule 7 scheduled exports for all the days from the week from the interested objects.
3. You can have prefered time as well.

II) 
1. Use dataloader.io: Using this tool you can also export.

Comment: but I want to take the backup on Daily basis and also , automate it and not do a daily manual backup

Comment: Data loader can be run by a batch file to run on a scheduled basis - that uses the command line option for data loader. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm

Comment: @krishsfdc , thanks. Is their a possible that we could backup our data from within Salesforce.

Comment: Do you want to store on your local?

Comment: we want to store the data on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You got following solutions to export data:

1. Using Data Management > Export Data wizard from within Salesforce to export selected or all objects data. Check this official [document](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=admin_exportdata.htm&siteLang=en_US). Using this option you can also schedule data exports and set a frequency as per your need.
2. Use command-line [data loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line) to run daily backups. Kindly explore the attached link and test with only one object initially. Once successful, then use the rest of them.
3. [Own-Backup](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000007p6RYEAY&tab=r) is an appexchange app, that just popped at the top while I tried to see if there is any solution in the appexchange. I haven't tried it but it is very cheap and the reviews are good. So, if you can spend couple of dollars then... go for ready-made solution.

Ciao!

[image]

Comment: thanks , but the data loader backup process is manual and we want an automated process for backup on daily basis. Also , the data export wizard can do a be scheduled to take backup on weekly basis but we want it on daily basis. Please suggest if any more suggestions

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the effort . Is their a way we could backup data within inside Salesforce.

Comment: From withing the salesforce? Use the appexchange app.